# Sonar - Is it possible to skip JavaSquidSensor and Findbugs Sensor during Sonar scan?

Tags: java, maven, continuous-integration, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I am using sonar 8.2(build 32929) to check code in team's CI pipeline and the Java project has 1440 files and 78K Loc.

I want to get new code coverage and duplication info from sonar scan and bugs, vulnerabilities, code smells are not needed. So I set java rule to empty to reduce time cost.

However, the sonar scan with empty rules cost too much time as well. Here is the log:

```
14:11:58  + mvn -U clean package sonar:sonar
14:16:51  [INFO] test and package done.
14:16:58  [INFO] --- sonar-maven-plugin:3.8.0.2131:sonar (default-cli) @ project 
14:16:59  [INFO] SonarQube version: 8.2.0
14:17:03  [INFO] 1448 files indexed
14:17:05  [INFO] Load project repositories (done) | time=157ms
14:19:01  [INFO] 951/951 source files have been analyzed
14:19:01  [INFO] Java Main Files AST scan (done) | time=115457ms
14:19:19  [INFO] 150/150 source files have been analyzed
14:19:19  [INFO] Java Test Files AST scan (done) | time=18692ms
14:19:19  [INFO] Sensor JavaSquidSensor [java] (done) | time=134323ms
14:19:39  [INFO] Sensor FindBugs Sensor [findbugs]
14:20:49  [INFO] Sensor FindBugs Sensor [findbugs] (done) | time=62128ms
14:21:01  [INFO] Analysis report uploaded in 714ms
14:21:01  [INFO] ANALYSIS SUCCESSFUL, you can browse https://my.sonar.url
14:21:01  [INFO] Note that you will be able to access the updated dashboard once the server has processed the submitted analysis report
14:21:01  [INFO] More about the report processing at https://my.sonar.url
14:21:02  [INFO] Analysis total time: 4:02.695 s
```

It shows that java AST scan takes about 2 mins(for duplication info and it's needed), Sensor JavaSquidSensor takes 2+ mins and Sensor FindBugs takes 1 mins.

Because I make java quality profile of the project to empty, I think JavaSquidSensor and FindBugsSensor are not needed during sonar scan.

So how can I skip or disable JavaSquidSensor and FindBugs Sensor for sonar scan?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

FindBugsSensor can be disabled by removing findbugs plugin. See this post https://community.sonarsource.com/t/is-it-possible-to-skip-javasquidsensor-and-findbugs-sensor-during-sonar-scan/41773

Still don't know how to disable JavaSquidSensor :'(

Comment: The issue with the Findbugs plugin running even though there wasn't any rules enabled has been fixed now. It was happening because the Findbugs JSP profile was the default profile and SonarQube enabled it even when there wasn't any JSP files.